# Вывод компилятора портит цветовую тему командной строки

Tags: c++, cmd, g++

[image]
Компилятор после проверки на ошибки меняет цветовую тему командной строки

Comment: А какая у вас цветовая тема стоит? Серый на желтом? Мсье знает толк. :)

Comment: Можно попробовать другой терминал. Вместо дефолтного CMD какой-нибудь ConEmu.

Comment: Да, cmd такое себе. Недаром WSL сделали

Comment: Благодарю, все попробую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо gcc ничего не знает о Вашей цветовой схеме. У Вас есть такие варианты

- отключить подсветку `-fdiagnostics-color=never`. можно сделать alias и тогда не нужно будет вводить.
- поправить подсветку под Вашу тему `export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'`. Когда подберете правильные значения, сохраните в .bash_rc или подходящий файл.

[детали](https://reversed.top/2015-10-25/enable-colorization-of-gcc-output/)

Comment: В `GCC_COLORS` не видно настройки цвета фона, так что не уверен, что поможет...

Comment: Вариант 3: перерыть исходники gcc, докопаться в чём там проблема, написать об этом в багзиллу и приложить патчик...

Comment: можно там и бэкграунд прописать - вот пример раскрасок https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94498/what-causes-this-green-background-in-ls-output

Comment: @KoVadim, а ты уверен, что в cmd оно заработает? gcc пишет, что значения в `GCC_COLORS` терминалозависимы...

Comment: в любом случае, всегда есть возможность запретить цветовую раскраску.